# Circulation visa - can I travel Greece first on my Schengen visa issued by French Consulate

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, greece, schengen-visas

I have a circulation visa(valid till march 2020) issued by French Embassy valid from march 2017. In my application I mentioned I will be visiting France(from London) for 4 days in mid April (which I will be), but due to some Official training I have to visit Greece(from London) for first two weeks of April, come back to London and then travel to France(as per the dates mentioned in my visa application), can I do so ? 
In a nutshell can I enter Greece on a schengen visa issued by France, which was earlier not the plan?
Does it impact my entry at Greece or France?

Comment: Note: "circulation visa" appears to be an idiosyncratically French term for a multiple-entry short-stay visa with a period of validity of at least one year. (Why they feel they need a separate word for that particular combination is not clear to me).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Henning. My only concern is while lodging the application I did not mentioned about Greece Travel. Though this travel popped up now and I have to travel here before traveling to France , I am bit curious if border control guys ask me why I entered in Greece before entering to France, as I will be coming back to UK and then proceed to France. So scenario is :- London--Greece--London (first two weeks of April, 2nd-13th April), then London--Paris--London (15th-18th April), hope this is not a problem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm nice one for your research, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Going to Greece first is allowed in and of itself, but you're supposed to get a visa from the country where you plan to spend most of the time. Not doing so can theoretically get you banned from Schengen for visa fraud.

In practice, it's unlikely the Greeks will even bat an eyelid - they'll probably just ask the usual questions about where you're going, for how long and for what purpose.

To err on the side of caution, though, bring as much paperwork as you can proving that the need to travel to Greece before France emerged **after** you were issued the visa. That's it!

Comment: I abstain from voting (a bad thing). Why are answering a duplicate?

Comment: Hi Crazydyre Thanks for the info. If I take the letter issued by the company stating the need for the training, would it do ? Also when I will be entering in France (after completing the visit to Greece) would France border authorities can raise any concern that why I went to Greece first ?

Comment: @user59077 Like I said, most likely no one will care. But yes, your letter from the company is good if it clearly states that the need for the training emerged after you got your French visa. Bring it both to Greece and France just in case.